# Can't go back to question list

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On the iOS app when reading a question, going to view a link in the browser control and coming back *not* by pressing Done but by swiping from the left border the back button on the question doesn't work. You can't go back to the question list and the app has to be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.1, shipping mid-February, or [iOS 9.3](https://twitter.com/rmondello/status/694442723332329472), whichever comes first.

Details are at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274037/235711